# Background-size: cover; doesnt cover screen

Tags: html, css

html newbie here, I'm trying to use `background-size: cover;` to make an image cover the full screen, [I'm still getting this gap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGoL9.png). How can I fix this? I feel like it has something to do with this part:

```
 body {
        background-image: url("hexagon.gif");
        background-size: cover;
```

I tried to replace the word body with .background-image but then the whole page became blank. How can I fix it? Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name= viewport content= width="device-width initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="background-image">
    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }


      body {
        background-image: url("hexagon.gif");
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 100hv;
        background-color: #cccccc;
    }
    </style>
  </div>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: `vh` not `hv` ....

Comment: It is not supposed to. You still have to add the width and height. Also `vh`, not `hv`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## For `cover`

What you have missed in your code is,

1. `height:100hv` is a syntax error,change it to `height:100vh`
2. we also need to set the width of container,you have missed it ,so add `width:100vw`

### Now the code you need is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name= viewport content= width="device-width initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="background-image">
    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }


      body {
        background-image: url("hexagon.gif");
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 100vh;/*CORRECTED SYNTAX ERROR*/
        width: 100vw;/*ADDED CODE*/
        background-color: #cccccc;
    }
    </style>
  </div>
</body>


</html>
```

##### Runnable Example:

```css
* {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }


      body {
        background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/1800/900");/*Example*/
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 100vh;/*CORRECTED SYNTAX ERROR*/
        width: 100vw;/*ADDED CODE*/
        background-color: #cccccc;
    }
```

---

## For stretching

use **`background-size:100vw 100vh;`**,
*or `background-size:100% 100%;`* ***if*** *both height and width are set as `height:100vh;width:100vw;`*

### The code you expect is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name= viewport content= width="device-width initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="background-image">
    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }


      body {
        background-image: url("hexagon.gif");
        background-size: 100vh 100vh;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-color: #cccccc;
        /*OR USE THE BELOW*/
        /*
        background-image: url("hexagon.gif");
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
        background-color: #cccccc;
        */
    }
    </style>
  </div>
</body>


</html>
```

##### Runnable Example:

```css
* {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }


      body {
        background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/1800/900");/*Example*/
        background-size:100vw 100vh;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-color: #cccccc;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really appreciate it :) Is there a way to keep the image always covering the page, without stretching it by instead zooming it?

Comment: ahh nvm figured it out with object-fit and cover haha

Comment: @user18746006 I have updated the code, check it! (I think you figured it out)